# ndb Query partial string matching

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, djangoappengine

This seems like it should be an easy question. But [the docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#filter_by_prop) don't seem to answer it. Using the example from them, I want to do this:

```
Account.query(Account.title == "best")
```

Except I want to match partial strings as well. So in this scenario:

```
acct = Account(title="the best account in the world")
```

an ndb query with argument "best" would match the `acct`.

The only option I see at the moment is to loop through `Account.query()` and match each `title` with `re.search` module in python. This doesn't seem like a good solution.

**Update:** I am also looking at `gql`. Doing this:

```
acct = ndb.gql('SELECT * from Account WHERE title LIKE '%best%')
```

returns a `Parse Error: Invalid WHERE Condition at symbol LIKE`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GQL doesn't have wildcards matching, to achieve that you will need to use the [full text search](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview).

Answer (score 11):

NOTE : This does not exactly answer the question, but someone looking for `starts with` might find this answer useful.

NDB's String field is indexed in a way where you can do greater than (`>=`) and less than (`<`) search. Assuming the following `Person` model:

```
class Person(ndb.Model):
    name         = ndb.StringProperty()
    name_lower   = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.name.lower())
```

You can do the following:

```
def search_by_text(text):
  text = text.lower()
  limit = text[:-1] + chr(ord(text[-1]) + 1)
  return Person.query(Person.name_lower >= text, Person.name_lower < limit).fetch(50)

p = search_by_text('kri')
```

The `limit` variable in this example will contain the string 'krj' and becomes the limit of the search values. The above will get you all the people whose name is greater than `kri` but less than `krj` and limit to the first 50 findings. Because of the limit, names like `kross` and `lark` will be filtered out.

Note: it's important that you have an `ndb.ComputedProperty` to contain a lower case version of the field you want to search on. Don't forget to add that!

Comment: This is the best solution I could find for a simple partial string matching search without needing to implement full text search.

Comment: I am unable to get any results with this solution. let me give you an example that what I want to achieve. suppose we have "This book is good and it contains a lot of information" query => "good".    Can I achieve this thing with your answer?

Comment: @SaimAbdullah I don't think so, but if you query "This book" then it would left-match to find the Entity you mentioned.  This answer matches strings that "start with" `text`

Answer (score 3):

For a (presumably) short field like a title, adding a repeated StringProperty that contains each word of the title (ignoring stop words, maybe) would allow you to match on words, and would be simpler than using the search API.

Comment: is that common practice? Seems like a hack.

Comment: I haven't implemented this myself, although I have seen it recommended other places (sorry, I don't have a link).